# WordPress meta box output on each line

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, foreach

Ive been looking for a way I can take a WordPress custom meta box's content that is entered on each line and output said contents on each line instead of in a single line, example:

```
Mon
Tues
Wed
Thurs
Fri
Sat
Sun
```

The above days of the week are entered in a custom meta box and I can output the contents of the meta box in my single.php with:

```
<?php if ( 'custom_post_type' == get_post_type() ) :
    $foobar_meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'meta-textarea', true );
    if( !empty( $foobar_meta ) ) : ?>
        <div class="jedi">
            <ul id="workload">
                <li><?php echo $foobar_meta; ?></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However when I run the code it outputs as: `<li>Mon Tues Wed Thurs Fri Sat Sun</li>`.  How can I target everything that is entered on a line and output individually as:

```
<li>Mon</li>
<li>Tues</li>
<li>Wed</li>
<li>Thurs</li>
<li>Fri</li>
<li>Sat</li>
<li>Sun</li>
```

Per my research I assume I would use an `array()` with a `foreach` but targeting each line I am having difficulties in what to use to call the meta box to run through.  I did look on the codex but I didn't see anything on how to target what I need.  So how can I with PHP take content that is entered on a single line and display it's look on the site?

Comment: You are using the textarea for metabox entrie which you want to display in  single line?

Comment: Yes.   I chose a textarea because the lines may range from 5 to 30..  the days of the week was just an example.  If you have a better suggestion I am for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see below code this may help you:

```
$string_arr = explode("\n", $foobar_meta);
$newstring = '<ul id="workload">';
foreach($string_arr as $single_string)
{
    $newstring .= '<li>' . $single_string . '</li>';
}
$newstring .= '</ul>';
echo $newstring;
```

OR

You can use like this too `$newstring .= '<li>' . str_replace("\n", '</li><li>', $single_string) . '</li>';` without loop and explode.

Comment: @Darth_Vader You can use another way like i edit my answser.

Comment: @Darth_Vader You can upvote this if this is helpful to you. :P :)